# Evaluating a triple summation ${\sum \sum \sum}_{1 \le i < j \le k \le 20} a_ia_ja_k$

Tags: summation, binomial-coefficients

> If $$a_i= \begin{cases} 1 && 1 \le i \le 10 \\ 2 && 11 \le i \le 20 \end{cases}  $$
>
> Find the value of $$\displaystyle {\sum \sum \sum}_{1 \le i < j \le k \le 20} a_ia_ja_k $$

I could only evaluate the summation when $1 \le i < j \le k \le 10$, by writing it as $\displaystyle {\sum _{i=1}^9\sum_{j=i+1}^{10} \sum_{k=j}^{10}} 1$ which came out to be $\displaystyle \binom{11}{3}$.

Should I make different cases like $i \le 10, 11 \le j \le k \le 20$ , etc.?

How do I evaluate it for the other cases? Is there any easier way to evaluate it without evaluating each sum one by one? Could there possibly be a combinatorial approach? I'd be delighted to see different approaches to this problem.

Comment: Is the answer 5280? (Rough calculation, working on writing an answer)

Comment: No, it is 4585.

Comment: Ah nvm, just wrote a program to find out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Essentially you want to count how many triplets $(i,j,k)$ will lead to $(a_i,a_j,a_k)$ to be one of the follow four possibilities: $(1,1,1),(1,1,2),(1,2,2),(2,2,2)$ (think about why these are the only possible outputs for $(a_i,a_j,a_k)$.

Now, count how many triplets of $(i,j,k)$ under the constraint $1\le i <j \le k\le 20$ will give you each of those four outputs. In particular,

$(a_i,a_j,a_k)=(1,1,1)$ if we have $1\le i <j \le k\le 10$. Say there are $A$ many such $(i,j,k)$.

$(a_i,a_j,a_k)=(1,1,2)$ if we have $1\le i <j \le 10$, $11\le k \le 20$. Say there are $B$ many such $(i,j,k)$.

$(a_i,a_j,a_k)=(1,2,2)$ if we have $1\le i \le 10$, $11\le j\le k \le 20$. Say there are $C$ many such $(i,j,k)$.

$(a_i,a_j,a_k)=(2,2,2)$ if we have $11\le i < j\le k \le 20$. Say there are $D$ many such $(i,j,k)$.

Then your final result will be $(1\cdot 1\cdot 1)A + (1\cdot 1\cdot 2)B + (1\cdot 2\cdot 2)C + (2\cdot 2\cdot 2) D$.

This turns it into a counting problem to find $A,B,C,D$.

(To check your work, you should get $A = 165, B = 450 , C = 550, D = 165$. And this gives the correct final sum.)

Comment: I got it correctly. thanks!, but still I would like to see if there is any other method also.

Comment: I see, it would be nice if there is some nice combinatorial interpretation of this (except "how many solutions to $1\le i < j \le k <10$", for instance).

Answer (score 2):

This approach is kind of bruteforce, but I could do it successfully using only pen and paper.

First, we'll consider the case $1 \le i \le 10$. We get a 2-dimensional matrix for the values that the addend can assume:

[image]

When you're doing this on paper, there's no need to write out all terms once you get the pattern, and an ellipsis works. Notice that **For a given $i$, we will sum the lower triangle of this matrix from the index $i+1$**. Therefore, as an example, for i=5, the sum will look like this:

[image]

The sum for $i$ is given as
$$S_i = \sum_{t=1}^{10-i}t + 20(10-i) + 220$$
Summing this from 1 to 10, we get
$$S_1 = \sum_{n=1}^9 \frac{n(n+1)}{2} + 20 \sum_{n=1}^9 n + 220 \times 10$$

We'll now consider $11 \le i \le 20$. In this case, **the lower triangle assumes a value of 8, and the same pattern follows**. The sum in this case is
$$S_2 = 8\sum_{n=1}^9 \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$$

Adding $S_1$ and $S_2$, we get
$$S = 9\sum_{n=1}^9 \frac{n(n+1)}{2} + 20 \sum_{n=1}^9 n + 2200$$

Evaluating this gives us $\boxed{S = 4585}$.

As an addendum, here's a simple python program I wrote to check the sum, and the additions that I made.

```
sum = 0
for i in range(1, 21):
    for j in range(i+1, 21):
        for k in range(j, 21):
            addend = 1
            if i > 10:
                addend *= 2
            if j > 10:
                addend *= 2
            if k > 10:
                addend *= 2
            sum += addend
            print(addend, end=" ")
        print("")

print(sum)
```

Answer (score 2):

Let

- $ A = \sum_{i < j < k } a_ia_ja_k$
- $ B = \sum_{i = j < k } a_ia_ja_k$
- $ C = \sum_{i < j = k } a_ia_ja_k$
- $ D = \sum_{i = j = k } a_ia_ja_k$

We're after $ A  + C$.

Clearly,

- $ 30^3 = ( \sum a_i)^3  = D + 3C + 3B + 6A$.
- $ D = 10 ( 1^3 + 2^3 ) = 90$
- $C = 2^2 ( 10 \times 10\times 1 + \frac{10 \times 9 }{ 2} \times 2 ) + 1^2 (\frac{10 \times 9 } { 2} \times 1) = 805$
- $ B = 1^2 (10\times 10 \times 2 + \frac{10 \times 9} { 2} \times 1) + 2^2 (\frac{10 \times 9 }{ 2} \times 2)  = 605$
- So, $A = \frac{30^3 - 90 - 3 \times 805 - 3 \times 605 }{ 6} = 3780$.

Hence, $ A + C = 4585$.

Comment: I also understood how is $D$ written, but can't understand how are $C$ and $B$ written.  I was evaluating $C$ as $a_1(a_2^2+a_3^2+\cdots+a_{20}^2)+a_2(a_3^2+a_4^2+\cdots+a_{20}^2)+\cdots+a_{19}a_{20}^2$, but unable to relate this to how you have done the calculation.

Comment: Also, I was having another doubt. We have a triple summation in the problem. But, $A+C$ is a double summation. I know that the union of range of $i,j,k$ in $A$ and range of $i,j,k$ in $C$ is the required range of $i,j,k$ in the question, but it's just that I am unable to see how the two are equivalent..just because in the problem, we have three summations, and now we have only two.

Comment: OR is it that the number of summation signs don't matter as long as required range is given, i mean is ${\sum \sum \sum}_{1\le i<j\le k\le 20}a_ia_ja_k=\sum_{1 \le i <j\le k \le 20} a_ia_ja_k$?

Comment: A) $C$ is written as $ a_{20}^2 \sum a_i + a{19}^2 + \sum a_i + ...$. For the $2^2$, what is the coefficient? Do you get $1$ $10\times10$ times and 2 $ 10 \times 9 / 2 $ times? B) A+C are triple summations, just that some indices are the same. C) Think about expanding $(\sum a_i)^3$. What do you get? Is it $D + 3C + 3B + 6A$? D) Yes, what I mean by $ \sum_{i<j\leq k} $ is shorthand for $ \sum \sum \sum { 1 \leq i < j < k \leq 20}$.